# How can we achieve VM Disk Encryption of unmanaged disk through Azure power shell

Tags: azure, powershell, encryption, virtual-machine, azure-disk

Can I perform Virtual Machine disk encryption for unman aged disk through power shell or ARM template

Comment: yes you can, read the docs

Comment: If the answer helps you solve the issue you can accept it. Or for more help, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform Virtual Machine disk encryption for unmanaged disk through PowerShell or template, also Azure CLI.

You can upload the encrypted VHD to your storage account and the encryption key material to your key vault. Then, provide the encryption configuration to enable encryption on a new Azure VM. For details about the steps follow [Encryption workflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/azure-security-disk-encryption-overview#encryption-workflow). And the command example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/azure-security-disk-encryption-linux).